# Rounded corners as a tangent in the right direction

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, rounded-corners

I want to split a path into two branches as in the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) [rectangle] {A};
  \node (B) [rectangle,above right=1cm and 4cm of A] {B};
  \node (C) [rectangle,below right=1cm and 4cm of A] {C};
  \draw [->, rounded corners=1cm] (A) -| +(2cm,0cm) |- (B);
  \draw [->, rounded corners=1cm] (A) -| +(2cm,0cm) |- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image: an awkward result]

There are many things wrong with that.

1. The left quater circle to C goes in the wrong direction
2. The circles should be a tangent to each other
3. They should meet in exactly the middle of A and BC

I think I still didn't get the thing about positioning in TikZ. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Old Style

### Positioning

Without the `on grid` option nodes are placed so that the distance between their border is correct. With `on grid` the `.center` anchors are used for calculation.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
    every node/.style={draw,fill,fill opacity=.1},
    helper node/.style={draw=none,fill=none,fill opacity=1},
    ruler/.style={line width=1.2\pgflinewidth,red,|-|,shorten >=-.5\pgflinewidth,shorten <=-.5\pgflinewidth},
    helper/.style={line width=1.2\pgflinewidth,red,-,dashed},
    } % for debugging purposes

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines] (-1,-2) grid (5,2);
  \node (A) [rectangle] {A};
  \node (B) [rectangle,above right=1cm and 4cm of A] {B};
  \node (C) [rectangle,below right=1cm and 4cm of A] {C};

  \draw[ruler] (A.north east) -- (A.north east |- B.south west) node[left,pos=.5,helper node] {1\,cm};
  \draw[helper] (A.north east |- B.south west) -- (B.south east);
  \draw[ruler] (A.north east) -- (A.north east -| B.south west) node[above,pos=.5,helper node] {4\,cm};
  \draw[helper] (A.north east -| B.south west) -- (B.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[on grid]
    \draw (-1,-2) grid (5,2);
  \node (A) [rectangle] {A};
  \node (B) [rectangle,above right=1cm and 4cm of A] {B};
  \node (C) [rectangle,below right=1cm and 4cm of A] {C};

  \draw[ruler] (A.center) -- (A.center |- B.center) node[left,pos=.5,helper node] {1\,cm};
  \draw[helper] (A.center |- B.center) -- (B.east);
  \draw[ruler] (A.center) -- (A.center -| B.center) node[above,pos=.5,helper node] {4\,cm};
  \draw[helper] (A.center -| B.center) -- (B.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

### Weird vertical lines

Don’t use `-|` for the first part of the path as the next point `(2cm,0cm)` is in fact already horizontal to the start point. Why is the weird line missing to `C`? Because it is the same as to `B`, apparently TikZ does a `>=` comparison with the *y*-values of the start and the target coordinate to calculate in which direction (left or right) the rounded circle have to go.

#### Code

```
  \draw [->, rounded corners=1cm] (A) -| +(2cm, 0cm   ) |- (B);
  \draw [->, rounded corners=1cm] (A) -| +(2cm,-0.01cm) |- (C);
```

#### Output

[image]

### Rounded circles

A rounded-circle radius of `1cm` needs at least `2cm` to do a full 90-degree-left  and 90-degree-right turn.
So you either have to use `.5cm` (= half of vertical distance) in the `on grid` version or calculate the needed radius within the path operation.

The easiest way to do this is the `let … in` operation which needs the `calc` library.
I provide a `curvy` style that takes one optional argument (default: `2cm`).

#### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\tikzset{
    curvy/.style={
        to path={
            let \p1=(\tikztostart),
                \p2=(\tikztotarget),
                \n1={abs(\y2-\y1)/2}
            in
            [rounded corners=\n1]
            (\tikztostart) -- + (0:#1) |- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
        }
    },
    curvy/.default=2cm,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) [rectangle] {A};
  \node (B) [rectangle,above right=1cm and 4cm of A] {B};
  \node (C) [rectangle,below right=1cm and 4cm of A] {C};
  \draw [->] (A) to[curvy]     (B);
  \draw [->] (A) to[curvy=3cm] (C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[on grid]
  \node (A) [rectangle] {A};
  \node (B) [rectangle,above right=1cm and 4cm of A] {B};
  \node (C) [rectangle,below right=1cm and 4cm of A] {C};
  \draw [->] (A) to[curvy]     (B);
  \draw [->] (A) to[curvy=1cm] (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image]

## New Style

You might want to check out the tree-producing facilities of TikZ.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    grow'=right,% clockwise, not counterclockwise (which would be "grow")
    level 1/.style={level distance=4cm,sibling distance=2cm},
    level 2/.style={level distance=2cm,sibling distance=1.5cm},
    edge from parent path={% the let ... in operator is only used to set rounded corners 
                           % to zero if parent and child are on the same height, but due to
                           % imprecision in the math-engine the comparison value is 0.001
        let \p1=(\tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor),
            \p2=(\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor),
            \n1={abs(\y2-\y1) > 0.001} 
        in
        [rounded corners=\n1*\tikzsiblingdistance/4]
             (\tikzparentnode\tikzparentanchor)
            -- + (0:\tikzleveldistance/2)
            |-   (\tikzchildnode\tikzchildanchor)
    }
]
\node {A}
    child {node {B} 
        child {node {B1}}
        child {node {B2}}
        child {node {B3}}
    }
    child {node {C}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Is it like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (A) [rectangle] {A};
  \node (B) [rectangle,above right=1cm and 4cm of A] {B};
  \node (C) [rectangle,below right=1cm and 4cm of A] {C};
  \draw [->, rounded corners=.7cm] (A) -- (0:2cm)  |- (B);
  \draw [->, rounded corners=.7cm] (A) -- (0:2cm) |- (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is how it should look like. Is there way to let 0.7 (which I suppose is 2^-0.5) be calculated automatically?