# drawing a line that stops at the edge of a shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Is there any way to modify this example so the line to "Hey!" stops at the edge of its node boundary? (Or at least stops drawing some distance short of its final position) I know I can use a `fill` but I don't want to in this case.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,>=latex, every node/.style={
    font=\sffamily\scriptsize
    },  
    circtext/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=8pt,inner sep=2pt},
    dot/.style={draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=0.6mm,inner sep=0pt}
]
{
\node[rectangle, fill=green!10!white!90!black, minimum width=6cm, minimum height=3cm] at (2,0){};
\node[circtext, fill=yellow](A) at (0,0) {A};
\node[circtext, fill=yellow, right=of A](B){B};
\draw[->] (A) -- node[dot, pos=0.5](C){}(B);
\draw[-] (C) --++(1,1) node[draw, inner sep=1pt]{Hey!};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Either add `above` or `anchor=<something>` or similar, or place the node before and then connect it. There also might be the possibility to use `mark connection node` from the `decoration.markings` library, though I prefer the node placed before.

Comment: You can shorten it by writing `\draw[-,shorten >=6pt] ...`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: how do I place a node at a specific offset (e.g. `(1,1)`) relative to another node?

Comment: Hmm, I just discovered `pin=`, that seems to sort of do what I want.

Comment: @JasonS You can write `at ($(nodename)+(1,1)$)`, depending on the type of positioning you want to do, but if I'm not mistaken it requires the `calc` library.

Comment: `\node at ([shift=(1,1)]C) {Hey!}` (or `at ($(C)+(1,1)$)` with the `calc` library) or `\node[above right=1 and 1 of C]{Hey}` (see `positioning` library) and possibily the `on grid` option.

Answer (score 3):

References:

- [Introduction to `positioning`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94386/package-pgf-math-error-unknown-operator-o-or-of/94396#94396)
- [Relative positioning of nodes in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15701/relative-positioning-of-nodes-in-tikz)
- [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386)
- [An overview of node positioning?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135305/16595)
- [Rounded corners as a tangent in the right direction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88185/rounded-corners-as-a-tangent-in-the-right-direction/88190#88190) (the first section)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds,calc}
\newcommand*\mydrawing{%
 % \node[rectangle, fill=green!10!white!90!black, minimum width=6cm, minimum height=3cm] at (2,0){};
  \node[circtext, left, fill=yellow](A) at (0,0) {A};
  \node[circtext, fill=yellow, right=of A](B){B};
  \draw[->] (A) -- node[dot, pos=0.5](C){}(B);}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={execute at begin picture=\mydrawing, node distance=2cm, >=latex,
  every node/.style={font=\sffamily\scriptsize},
  circtext/.style={draw,circle,minimum size=8pt,inner sep=2pt},
  dot/.style={draw,circle,fill=black,minimum size=0.6mm,inner sep=0pt},
  gridded}}
\begin{document}
\tikz\draw (C) --++(1,1) node[draw, inner sep=1pt]{Hey!};
\tikz\node[inner sep=1pt, draw] at ([shift={(1,1)}]C) {Hey!}              edge (C);
\tikz\node[inner sep=1pt, draw] at ($(C)+(1,1)$) {Hey!}                   edge (C);
\tikz\node[inner sep=1pt, draw, above right=1 and 1 of C] {Hey!}          edge (C);
\tikz[on grid]\node[inner sep=1pt, draw, above right=1 and 1 of C] {Hey!} edge (C);
\tikz\path (C) ++(1,1) node[draw, inner sep=1pt] {Hey!}                   edge (C);
\tikz\path[pin distance=1cm] (C)
  [late options={pin={[draw, inner sep=1pt, pin edge={thin,black}]above right:Hey!}}];
\tikz\path[every pin edge/.style={thin,black}, pin distance=1cm] (C)
  [late options={pin={[draw, inner sep=1pt]above right:Hey!}}];
% This is the same as saying \node[pin=…] (C) {};
\end{document}
```